# sqlalchemy: unambiguous remote/local column with backref

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Aim; to have full cascade save/load/delete with SQLAlchemy from the root entity (scenario) through Segment and then Timeseries.

Question; from a parent class, BaseSegment, with multiple properties that link to a child class, Timeseries, whose table links back with segment_id, how do I configure a backref?

```py
class Timeseries(Base):
    __tablename__ = "timeseries"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    # values etc
    segment_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("public.segments.id"))

class BaseSegment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "segments"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    actual_effect_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey(Timeseries.id))
    actual_effect = relationship(
        EffectVarTimeseries,
        backref="segment",
        foreign_keys=[actual_effect_id],
        remote_side=Timeseries.segment_id,
    )
    predicted_effect_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey(Timeseries.id))
    predicted_effect = relationship(
        EffectVarTimeseries,
        backref="segment",
        foreign_keys=[predicted_effect_id],
        remote_side=Timeseries.segment_id,
    )
```

Crashes like this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class BaseSegment->segments'. Original exception was: **Relationship BaseSegment.actual_effect could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments**.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.

In particular, when I have `remote_side=Timeseries.segment_id` I get this crash.

If I remove a bit of the config above, instead of the Session cascade-writing from segment -> timeseries, I get this error*:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "segment_id" of relation "timeseries" violates not-null constraint

Furthermore, if I generate the UUID id from the calling python code, the DB complains that basically the segment's Id doesn't exist (yet!)**.

I can't just do a `back_populates` because I don't know whether the Timeseries is for a `predicted_effect` or `actual_effect`. How do I model this?

---

***Details, full error:**

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "segment_id" of relation "timeseries" violates not-null constraint
E       DETAIL:  Failing row contains (b2dff54f-ff1c-4457-8cf1-0783ea2acdbb, effect_var, null, revenue, EUR, Resulting amount revenue per day, {45753.00000000003,63875.00000000002,12731.999999999998,56585,37..., datetime64[ns], D, null, null, null, revenue, null).
E
E       [SQL: INSERT INTO public.timeseries (id, type, variable_name, variable_unit, variable_description, values, dtype, freq, segment_id, funnel_level, treatment, behavioural_segment_id, effect) VALUES (%(id)s, %(type)s, %(variable_name)s, %(variable_unit)s, %(variable_description)s, %(values)s::FLOAT[], %(dtype)s, %(freq)s, %(segment_id)s, %(funnel_level)s, %(treatment)s, %(behavioural_segment_id)s, %(effect)s)]
E       [parameters: {'id': UUID('b2dff54f-ff1c-4457-8cf1-0783ea2acdbb'), 'type': 'effect_var', 'variable_name': 'revenue', 'variable_unit': 'EUR', 'variable_description': 'Resulting amount revenue per day', 'values': [45753.00000000003, 63875.00000000002, 12731.999999999998, 56585.0, 37048.99999999997, 19938.999999999985, 28346.999999999985], 'dtype': 'datetime64[ns]', 'freq': 'D', 'segment_id': None, 'funnel_level': None, 'treatment': None, 'behavioural_segment_id': None, 'effect': 'revenue'}]
```

**For the client-generated UUID:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "timeseries" violates foreign key constraint "timeseries_segment_id_fkey"
```

#### References

- [backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html)
- [working with related objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html)
- [annotations recommended](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-annotations)
- [mailing list similar error](https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/Ir7P5CkOijU)